# JavaScript Password Generator - multiple random values from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, random

I am a newcomer to JavaScript, and have been battling with this relatively simple program for a few days now.

The program: I have a website with a button on. When you click the button, a password is generated (from an array) and displayed for the user.

The problem: "function generate()" displays the single same generated character 10 times, instead of 10 different characters 10 times, which naturally would make a much stronger password. I want it to randomize 10 different characters into a password, not the same character 10 times. So the program works, but not as I intended.

I have created a JSfiddle **containing comments** for display. Note that document.write is disabled in JSfiddle, so the result is set to show in console.

https://jsfiddle.net/ohstmbym/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  <button onclick="generate()">Button</button>
  </head>
<body>
<script>
  var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  randomLetter = arr[Math.floor(arr.length * Math.random())];
  function generate () {for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {document.write(randomLetter); } }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Important**: I would like to **understand** what is wrong with the code/how to fix it - I am not just looking for somebody to solve it for me with no explanation. If you want to help me solve the problem, I am very thankful, but please explain what you do. And also, please don't rewrite the code completely like in rewriting the entire program to make it work; I am looking for solutions/explanations, not somebody write the whole thing up. If it's **completely** wrong and need to be entirely rewritten, please simply explain in words what should've been done instead.

Still, thank you very much in advance, I appreciate any help.

(P.S. I know only lower case letters for password generation will be of weaker security, but this is only for experimentation)

Comment: You are setting randomLetter only once, why would you except it to be 10 different random letters? For that you need to set it inside the for

Comment: @juvian thanks I've been trying to work my way around this, e.g. multiplying randomLetter * 10 and such, but with no luck. I will try to put it inside the for loop ASAP (I am AFK for a little while though). Thank you very much for the answer

Comment: relevant xkcd https://xkcd.com/221/ :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not *regenerating the random element*, you're caching a random element *once* in `randomLetter` so it's always the same. The value of the variable *will not change* every time you refer to it. Put it inside the for loop to regenerate the number every iteration:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
function generate () {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var randomLetter = arr[Math.floor(arr.length * Math.random())];
    document.write(randomLetter); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, I will try to do that later today (I am about to be AFK for a little while). Appreciate that you took the time to view the code.

Comment: may I ask you why you changed "randomLetter" to "var randomLetter" ? Is there any advantages by making it a variable? Because I made it work with simply "randomLetter = ..." without having it a variable. Thanks a bunch for the help :-)

Comment: @thesystem The `var` declares the variable. Without var you're implicitly creating a global variable which is almost never good.